# Change ImageView for a few seconds and pause UI

Tags: android, multithreading, imageview, runnable, postdelayed

Sorry, I keep on trying to adapt the tokens, but somehow I can't manage this one.

I have the following code:

```
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      public void run(){
      SplashImage.setImageDrawable(aktieknop);}

      });

  },SplashTime);
  }
```

Like this the code 'works':

```
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

    // runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      public void run(){
      SplashImage.setImageDrawable(aktieknop);}

    //  });

  },SplashTime);
  }
```

Can you please help me solving this silly issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since you have already tried something, post the relevant parts of your code and explain specifically what isn't working. If you just want a link about Threads then check out http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: Read the logCat message first .. or paste here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call this code line " `SplashImage.setImageDrawable(nSplashImage);` " from your run method in a runOnUIThread() method like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    SplashImage.setImageDrawable(nSplashImage);
}
```

});

This is because you cannot change UI components on a non UI thread.

Comment: Thanks, I made some new final variables and think indeed (looking at the LogCat) that I also need to run it on the UI thread. I now have this in total, only the ;}) I'm not getting right to test.

Comment: Your welcome.. you can read about AsyncTask too.. it can help you a lot in android multitasking...

Answer (score 0):

For the splash Screen you can use the Handler and send the delayed message.

```
Handler splashHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             super.handleMessage(msg);
              //Here you can do what ever you want

           }
         };
```

int SPLASHTIME=2000;//your wish

```
splashHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, SPLASHTIME);
```